# Have been getting many OverQuotaExceptions using Mail API in App Engine in the last few days, despite being way below quota according to the console

Tags: java, email, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

In the last few days we are getting many of the following error in our App Engine logs:

com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call mail.Send() required more quota than is available.

This is despite being very much under quota based on what I can see in the Google Cloud console. The content of our emails that we send out has remained the same, and there have been no significant increases in our traffic recently. Note that not all Mail API calls are failing, many are still successful.

Is this a known issue with the App Engine Mail API right now? There have been no changes on our end that justify this, so I have to imagine this problem in on Google's end.

**New, September 19**: It seems that since this issue happened and was resolved, a different issue has come up. Some of the emails that we send out appear to be successfully sent out from an API perspective, but they are not received by any of the recipients (and are not in Spam folders). I believe this to be a small percentage of total emails that we send out on a daily basis, but some of our users have certainly noticed..

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Me too! Starting at about 17:30 UTC on 2023-08-18 a majority (but not all) of our outgoing mail requests from App Engine (python 2.7 environment) have been getting exceptions with the same message, even though the App Engine console shows our daily mail quota far from full (like 11% used). We have been sending mail this way since 2015. Our Silver support plan was discontinued by Google last year. I'm trying to buy Customer Care Standard, but that purchase is failing inexplicably. What support plan do you have? They won't help answer this? What is it for then? Please post whatever you learn!

Comment: I created a bug report about this, which anyone affected may want to upvote and comment on. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/296736590

Comment: I also have the same problem as of 18.8.23
In the console it appears that I have a limit of 120 emails per day, before that I would send several thousand a day, I have been working with them since 2015 and it worked perfectly
I work with java 8
Today I talked to them in chat and they told me they would check it

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=(xxx) you can see that "Mail messages sent to non-admins per day" have been lowered to 120, inexplicably.

This sudden change without any warning (that I know of) is absolutely dramatic and blocks our entire online invoicing business.